# How to create a serial number tied to a changing datetime with rank or any other function using sql server

Tags: sql-server, using, rank

I want to generate a unique row number tied to SerialNumber, VersionId and VersionDate; the only caveat is if the version flips back to old version I want to restart the Srno again from 1. In short instead of SrNo 5 and 6 I need 1 and 2.  Any help on this is much appreciated.

```
create table #t1 ( SerialNumber int, VersionId int, VersionDate datetime)

insert into #t1 ( SerialNumber, VersionId, VersionDate )
values ( 13000, 1,'2018-06-01 11:09:41'),
( 13000,1,'2018-06-01 11:39:41 '),(13000,1,'2018-06-01 12:09:41'),(13000,1,'2018-06-01 12:39:41'),(13000,2,'2018-06-01 13:09:42'),(13000,2,'2018-06-01 13:39:42'),(13000,1,'2018-06-01 14:01:42'),(13000,1,'2018-06-01 14:51:40')

select SerialNumber,VersionId , VersionDate, rank() OVER( PARTITION BY  SerialNumber,VersionId  ORDER  BY   VersionDate) As SrNo
FROM #t1
order by VersionDate


SerialNumber    VersionId   VersionDate SrNo
13000   1   2018-06-01 11:09:41.000 1
13000   1   2018-06-01 11:39:41.000 2
13000   1   2018-06-01 12:09:41.000 3
13000   1   2018-06-01 12:39:41.000 4
13000   2   2018-06-01 13:09:42.000 1
13000   2   2018-06-01 13:39:42.000 2
13000   1   2018-06-01 14:01:42.000 5
13000   1   2018-06-01 14:51:40.000 6
```

Comment: We need a little more information. Is this a serial number for a product of some sort or by serial, do you just mean "sequential"? (or something else)

Answer (score 0):

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   SerialNumber, versionid, VersionDate, maxdate
               FROM     #t1 a
                        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    MAX(versiondate) maxdate
                                      FROM      #t1
                                      WHERE     VersionDate < a.VersionDate
                                                AND VersionId <> a.VersionId
                                    ) k1                        
             )
    SELECT  SerialNumber
          , VersionId
          , VersionDate
          , RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY maxdate ORDER BY versiondate ) AS srno
    FROM    cte
```

Comment: It is definitely working @shiv-sidhu  but was trying to speed up the query performance as it takes over 25 seconds to shift through 14K rows. We have tons of SerialNumber and was trying to see if any improvement can be made in terms of returning the result set much faster.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am glad it worked for you. The way SO works is you have to at-least share some things you've already attempted towards resolving the problem..